# If the series $a_n$ is convergent, is the series $(-1)^n \sqrt{a_n}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Given that series $a_n$ converge (which is positive), I have to figure out if the series $(-1)^n \sqrt{a_n}$ is convergent. I would like to know if my proof is correct:

First, I am looking at the series $\sqrt{a_n}$. Since it is always true that $\sqrt{a_n} \leq a_n$, by Basic Comparison Test the series $\sqrt{a_n}$ is convergent, and this implies that the series $(-1)^n \sqrt{a_n}$ is also convergent by absolute convergence test. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you sure it is always true that ${\sqrt{a_n} \leq a_n}$?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose The question assumes that the series $a_n$ is a convergent, non-negative series. So that should be true for all $a_n$, right?

Comment: Well, for example - ${\sqrt{0.5}\approx 0.707\dots > 0.5}$

Comment: Right ... so is there any other way I can prove this?

Comment: Perhaps thinking of some examples could help. Take ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}$. This (famously) converges. Now take ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}}$. This famously diverges. But ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}$ (again, famously) converges. How would we prove that last sum converges?

Comment: Are you asking about _series_ or _sequences_? Hard to tell, since you use the word "series" but there are no series visible in the post, only sequences...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I meant series (infinite sums)

Comment: Then you should edit the post and _write_ infinite sums! Note what happens when you write \sum_{j=1}^n inside two dollar signs...

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{k^2}&n=2k\\\frac1{4k^2}&n=2k-1\end{cases}$$